# Qml: pass argument as part of URL when loading components from files

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

Is there a mechanism to pass URL arguments in Qml and extract them later?:

```
StackView.push("Page.qml?#label2);
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "pass arguments" when creating an object from a component.

```
StackView.push(component.createObject(null, {"someProperty" : someValue}))
```

So you can use an auxilary component to facilitate that:

```
Component { id: component; url: "Page.qml" } // or
property Component component: Qt.createComponent("Page.qml") // or
Component { id: component; Page {} }
```

Or if you don't want to pollute with extra stuff, you can directly:

```
StackView.push(Qt.createComponent("Page.qml").createObject(null, {"someProperty" : someValue}))
```

Lastly, not a good idea to have your `StackView` named `StackView`, I mean in QML **neither properties nor ids can begin with uppercase character**.

Comment: But singleton identifiers can start with uppercase characters. If you use the `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`-StackView you have the same option as when you create a component, to add give a second argument like: `myStackView.push('Page.qml', { property1 : 42, property2: 'hello world' })`

Comment: Not exactly a good idea to call a singleton `StackView` either ;) Something more descriptive would be better. Also, I doubt the OP uses a singleton, or that a GUI element singleton makes any sense or is even possible to begin with.

Comment: It is possible to have `Item`s as `singleton`. You can reparent them, to where ever you want, to have them shown.

Comment: Seeing how singletons are context-less, that could be problematic.

Comment: I am not a judge of this.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create an object manually. Just do this

```
stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("qrc:/U/R/L/item.qml"), {someCustomProperty: 0})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT worked:

```
navigationBar.push(Qt.resolvedUrl('qrc:/Pages/BookListPage.qml'), {argument:'test'})
```

But this is worked (to create an object):

```
navigationBar.push(Qt.createComponent("qrc:/Pages/BookListPage.qml").createObject(null, {argument:'test'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually according to the QT docs ([http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html][1]) the recommended way is to pass a property list containing at least the the following minimum entries to the push function ():

- **item**: this property is required, and holds the item to be pushed.
- **properties**: a list of QML properties to be assigned to the item upon push. These properties will be copied into the item at load
  time, or when the item will become the current item (normally upon
  push).

so we get

```
    navigationBar.push({item: Qt.resolvedUrl("MyRectangle.qml"), properties: {"color" : "red"}});
```